# Can I offer a bounty to an accepted answer that already exists?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I want to offer a bounty to an answer. That answer was for a question I asked on Stack Overflow.

But when I click the "start bounty" link, it asks me to select an option. It seems that the bounty will not be offered to the answer that I have already accepted.

What I want to do is offer a bounty to the answer that I accepted earlier. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can offer a bounty using the “Reward existing answer” option.

> [image]

What you cannot do is immediately award the bounty — you have to wait 24 hours. Think of this period as an opportunity for people to write even better answers.

After the 24 hour period, you can award the bounty to any answer you choose (except one you wrote yourself).

Comment: ohh.i haven't look carefully.so it's possible.